# Remove Bullet Points from WooCommerece Primary Sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to remove Bullet Points from the Woo Commerece Categories widget on Wordpress, its on the primary sidebar.

[image]

Help please?

Comment: please post your code which you tried..

Comment: Welcome to SO , please follow [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) , it will tell how to ask a great question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add this css in your style file

```
ul.product-categories {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit in css

.widget_product_categories ul li::before
{list-style: none;}